# Debug Parity and ethminer

Tags: parity, ethminer, stratum

I can not mine on a private blockchain using parity in stratum mode and ethminer.

```
Parity Ethereum version: 2.1.9
ethminer: 0.16
Operating system: Ubuntu 18.04
```

Here is the output from ethminer:

```
m 01:12:05 ethminer ethminer 0.16.1
 m 01:12:05 ethminer Build: linux/release
cu 01:12:05 ethminer Using grid size: 8,192, block size: 128
 i 01:12:05 ethminer Configured pool 127.0.0.1:8008
 i 01:12:05 main     Selected pool 127.0.0.1:8008
 i 01:12:05 stratum  Stratum mode detected: STRATUM
 i 01:12:05 stratum  Subscribed!
 i 01:12:05 stratum  Authorized worker 
 i 01:12:05 stratum  Established connection with 127.0.0.1:8008 at  [127.0.0.1:8008]
 i 01:12:05 stratum  Spinning up miners...
 i 01:12:05 cuda-0   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 i 01:12:05 cuda-1   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 i 01:12:08 cuda-0   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 i 01:12:08 cuda-1   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 m 01:12:10 ethminer Speed 0.00 Mh/s gpu0 0.00 gpu1 0.00 [A0] Time: 00:00
 i 01:12:11 cuda-1   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 i 01:12:11 cuda-0   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 i 01:12:14 cuda-1   No work. Pause for 3 s.
 i 01:12:14 cuda-0   No work. Pause for 3 s.
```

Here is how I invoke ethminer:

`/opt/ethminer/bin/ethminer -R -U -P stratum+tcp://127.0.0.1:8008`

Here is my parity .toml file:

```
[parity]
chain = "/home/parity/my-chain-spec.json"

[network]
reserved_peers = "/home/parity/reserved-peers.txt"
min_peers = 15

[rpc]
hosts = [""]
cors = [""]

[account]
unlock = ["0x00..."]
password = ["/home/parity/keyPass.txt"]

[mining]
author = "0x00..."

[stratum]
```

`netstat -tulpn | grep '8008' shows:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8008          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6699/parity
```

Do you see something I do not see?

ethminer works when I use it on this worker with the same flags connected to a stratum pool.

Parity has 15 peers (and that is min_peers in toml file).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrading to ethminer 0.18 alpha got this working but I don't know why 0.16 did not work with Parity 2.1.9